# Issue when implementing a map-like iterator in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I just finish to implement a generic skip list in C++ an I want to bring it an
STL map-like iterator.
The problem arise when overloading the "->" operator: it is required to return a reference to an iterator::value_type, which in my case is std::pair, with K being the key type and V the value type of my map-like container.
The code is the following:

```
value_type& operator->() { return value_type(inner->key, inner->value); }
```

The compiler return me some hatred messages about references to temporary objects, and I 
completely agree with him; me question is: How the hell should I do to return a reference
to a pair without having to put a pair member in my iterator class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value_type& operator->() { return value_type(inner->key, inner->value); }
```

Your return type is a reference to a `value_type`, but you return a locally-created instance, which would be destroyed at the end of the function/operator scope (i.e. the closing `}`.) So you return a garbage reference, which is why your compiler hates you.

If you instead return *by value*, you will have correct and functional code. (Whether or not you *should* return by value depends on the type of `value_type`.)

```
value_type operator->() { return value_type(inner->key, inner->value); }
```

Even better would be to maintain a single `value_type` as a member field of your class, but you say you don't want to, so this is the only other realistic option.

Comment: Ok, I missed that point, I thought it was required to return a reference. I have another question related to map iterator which digress a little from my initial question:  why do STL iterators such as the map one have value_type of the form std::pair<const K, V> instead of std::pair<const K&, V&>. Why making one more copy of the key and value instead of just returning references to these ?

Comment: Because enforcing a reference-only contract like that is often more complex, more fragile, or more expensive than enforcing a value-only contract.

Comment: But is it considered bad practice to use references instead of values ? Will some STL algorithms stop to work ?

Comment: Perhaps you should read up on C++ references, what they are, how they work, and what they're for. :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't formulate my question well. What I want to know is wether using references as components of the pair returned by the iterator is considered a poor design, and goes against the C++ idiom and if so, why ?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're putting into the `pair`. Your question doesn't really have a universal answer. What types in particular are you working with?

Comment: Any, the types are those provided by the user as key/value template parameters.

Comment: Then your question still doesn't have a universal answer. Some types should not generally be passed by value (streams come to mind.) Others should not generally be passed by reference (primitives like `int` come to mind.) It all depends on what *specifically* you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, `operator->` should return a pointer, or else something that has its own `operator->()` method.  But if you don't have a `value_type`, that is, a `pair<const K,V>` stored, you can't easily return a pointer to it.

Can you change the definition of `inner` so that it is or contains a `pair`?  You can add accessors like `key()` and `value()` in to avoid the confusing `first` and `second` in most places.

Or, depending on how much like `std::map` you need this to act, maybe you should use a different `value_type` typedef that describes what you actually do have.

Answer (score 1):

operator->() should only return values which are pointers or have overloaded operator->() functions defined for them. The point of this function is not so much to perform the '->' operation itself, but to provide the object or pointer for which the '->' operator will operate on.

In your case, to accomplish this you would need to return a pointer to pair. If you really would like to avoid having the pair stored inside your class, you could have the function return a smart pointer to a freshly allocated pair, that way no memory leaks occur during the operation.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing in your snipped is creating a new instance of value_type. This object will of course be deleted once the function/method operator->() is left, which leaves your reference that you just returned pointing to nowhere.

What you should do is return a reference to the appropriate element already IN your list.